# Retriving properties values using jboss 6 properties service

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I have a properties file inside conf directory in a jboss 6 server.

How i can get a group or all the key and values from that file inside my application:

```
<attribute name="URLList">
  ./conf/crawler.properties
</attribute>
```

thanks

Comment: Properties reside at the available place on the server side, thus it cold be reached via url.

Comment: i am trying to use org.jboss.util.property.* classes to retrive keys and values... but that dont work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this, but using `java.util.Properties`:

```
String path = System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.url") + propertiesFileName;
Properties props = new Properties();
URL url = new URL(path);
props.load(url.openStream());
```

The `Properties` class has all the neccessary methods for reading key-value-pairs (it also implements `Map<Object,Object>`).